# Unity C# unusual obit

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I was making a game about space, like KSP and other space simulator game.
[This is the normal orbit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysBLO.jpg)
The normal orbit is a circle.
[But this is my orbit .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hz8e.png)

I try using Collider2D and Point effector2D to create gravity but it is not well too.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour {

public float Mass;

private List<GameObject> InRangeObjects;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InRangeObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    ApplyGravity();
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{
    List<GameObject> InRangeObjectstemp = new List<GameObject>();
    InRangeObjectstemp.Add(col.gameObject);
    InRangeObjects = InRangeObjectstemp;
    ////////////////////////////////////        
}

public void ApplyGravity()
{        
    foreach (GameObject Ga in InRangeObjects)
    {
        float distance = (Ga.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

        if (Ga.GetComponent<TotalDataStorer>().UseInGameGravity == true)
        {
            float GravitationalPule = (6.673e-11f * ((Mass * Ga.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass) / (distance * distance))) * Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(GravitationalPule);
            Vector3 temp = Ga.transform.position - transform.position;
            Ga.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(temp.x, temp.y) * GravitationalPule * -1) ;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have a flower like orbit, how can I fix this?

Comment: You might also be interested in [this SE answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/10867) regarding geosynchronous orbits.

Comment: sorry , i can not understand the physics in that link , i'm only a secondary 1 student , may be you can give me part of your code to me ? thank you for your help !

Comment: If you want to make a (somewhat) realistic simulation game you will need to understand the physics and mathematics. If not you will just have to come up with something that works for your game (in other words: looks "good enough")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your object is not traveling fast enough, that is an orbit of a slow moving outer object not a regular "circular" orbit, you will have to tweak the speed at which your object is moving. In general you got everything right, it is an orbit, and it is mathematically correct, just you need to get the initial conditions correct.

Oh and you spelled pull wrong in GravitationalPule, it is GravitationalPull.